# Update element text when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("#readMain").delegate("span", "click", function() {
    var toSend = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(function() {return "test1";});
    $.post('/render/', {'word': toSend}, function(data){
        $(this).text(data);
        alert(data); //for testing
    });
});
```

I'm trying to have the word clicked updated. It works fine the first time (it changes to 'test1'), but after the post call, it doesn't work anymore?

What am I doing wrong

Comment: FYI, `.delegate` is deprecated, use `.on`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in that context refers the first time to the "span", the second time it refers to the window object.
Besides that, delegate is old jQuery, you can use '.on' now.

You'll nee to update the function like this:

```
$("#readMain").on("click", "span", function() {
    var span = $(this);
    var toSend = span.text();
    $.post('/render/', {'word': toSend}, function(data){
        span.text(data);
        alert(data); //for testing
    });
});
```

Comment: @arcanelogic Thanks great. It would be nice if you'd accept my awnser as the correct on if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't refers to `span` element in `$.post()` callback method, store the reference of `$(this)` in a variable and use it wherever required.

```
//Store the reference 
var _this = $(this);
$.post('/render/', {'word': toSend}, function(data){
    //Use it later
    _this.text(data);
    alert(data); //for testing
});
```

---

Additionally, `delegate()` is deprecated use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#readMain").on("click", "span", function() {
    //Store the reference 
    var _this = $(this);

    var toSend = _this.text();
    _this.text("test1");
    $.post('/render/', {'word': toSend}, function(data){
        _this.text(data);
        alert(data); //for testing
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is only valid in the current scope which means every function, class, closure, ..., has it's on `this`. Save a reference to your first `this` in a var to access it later.

```
$("#readMain").delegate("span", "click", function() {
    var span = $(this);
    var toSend = span.text();
    span.text(function() {return "test1";});

 $.post('/render/', {'word': toSend}, function(data){
        span.text(data);
        alert(data); //for testing
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The context in $.post callback will be changed. You can declare a variable and set the context. See the code below.

```
$("#readMain").on("span", "click", function() {
    var self = $(this),
        toSend = self.text();
    self.text(function() {return "test1";});
    $.post('/render/', {'word': toSend}, function(data){
        self.text(data);
        alert(data); //for testing
    });
});
```